# jquery mobile popup is showing a blue layer on it while opening

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, popup, html5-apps

I am using mobile jquery to develop html5 app. But i am facing some issue in popup.

I tried the below code.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"  data-history="false">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
  <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```

Popup is working fine with computer and mobile browser. But i test it on a android mobile after convert it into app(.apk). Then a blue transparent layer is showing over the popup if i click somewhere on the mobile screen this layer will remove from the popup.

how to remove this blue transparent screen.

[Sample Code - JJFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sourabh1985/QuquL/)

[Download sample application from here](http://www.apkinstall.com/files/popuptest_54.apk.png).

Comment: android 4.2 - showing problem. but android 4.0 not showing any layer. could be a android version issue?

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you must override css:

```
.flip.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
}
```

Tested and working ;)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been added to the jquery-mobile issue tracking system here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7533

Follow that link to track the solution.  It does appear to be a styling issue...